# Can I return a null from a LINQ statment if the input is null?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code but it gives an error when examples is null. Is there a way I could retain this as a one line LINQ and have it set sampleSentences to null if result.examples = null?

```
 var sampleSentences = result.examples
             .Select(ex => new SampleSentence { Text = ex })
             .ToList();
```

Comment: I recommend sampleSentences is an empty sequence on null input.. it breaks the contract asked for, but empty sequences are generally so much nicer to propagate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using C#6, you can write:

```
var sampleSentences = result?.examples
         ?.Select(ex => new SampleSentence { Text = ex })
         .ToList();
```

Otherwise you can write:

```
var sampleSentences = 
         result.examples == null 
             ? null 
             : result.examples
                 .Select(ex => new SampleSentence { Text = ex })
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: You only need one questionmark after examples if you are sure only examples could be null.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz You're absolutely right - nice spot

Answer (score 2):

You can use C#6 feature:  `?`

```
result.examples?
     .Select(ex => new SampleSentence { Text = ex })
     .ToList();
```

This will perform `Select` only if `result.examples` is not `null`.

Comment: And it returns `null` if `result.examples` is `null` (important!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just go with:

```
var sampleSentences = result.examples?
             .Select(ex => new SampleSentence { Text = ex })
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use ternary operator

```
var sampleSentences = result.examples != null ? result.examples
             .Select(ex => new SampleSentence { Text = ex })
             .ToList() : null;
```